# How do I find the dot net encoding codepage for Latin1?

Tags: c#, character-encoding

Most webpages have a meta tag that specifies an encoding, for instance:
meta content-"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1".

If I take a web page that has been saved to my PC, and read it with

```
dim enc as encoding

 enc = encoding.UTF8 
my.computer.filesystem.readalltext(myfilename,  enc)
```

What encoding should I use?
There is ASCII, there is UTF-8, there is Latin1 (English, Spanish, French, etc) and there is windows-1251 (and more)

My first guess was utf-8, but that read in some characters the wrong way.  I found out that the meta tag charset above is equivalent to 'latin1' but I don't know how to set the enc variable to 'latin1'.   In fact, the intellisense for encoding gives only a few options, like ASCII and UTF8.

So how do I get an encoding in dot-net that is equivalent to latin1? (assuming latin1 is what I want)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
public static System.Text.Encoding Latin1 { get; }
```

as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.latin1?view=net-6.0)